# Jquery/JS - Find input based on value attribute and trigger a click on it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, shopify

I have the following html in shopify:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.product-single__thumbnail').click(function() {

    var secondClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
    console.log(secondClass);
    if (secondClass == 'is-selected') {
      console.log('Skip');
    } else if (secondClass == '') {
      console.log('Skip');
    } else {
      console.log(secondClass);
      //       CODE NEEDS TO GO HERE TO TRIGGER CLICK
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="variant-field">
  <input id="option-Midnight-1" class="visually-hidden variant-input" type="radio" name="Color" value="Midnight" data-single-option-selector="" data-index="option1" checked="checked">
  <label class="variant__button-label" for="option-Midnight-1">Midnight</label>
</div>
```

I have a variable in JS that I want to use in the find function in order to find the above mentioned value (called Midnight in this example) before triggering a click on it.

My current code to get the variable is below (actually a class name that I grab which matches the value on the input that needs to be clicked)

Comment: are you trying to trigger a click on the `secondClass` variable?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do here. You have conflicting `if` clauses in your code.

Comment: Where is 'product-single__thumbnail' class in your HTML?

Comment: Nothing is clear from the current example, need to improve it for better assistance